# Could adding a column with month identificator increase queries performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Situation is as follows. There is a table with about 40 000 000 rows per month times 24 months, so lets say almost 1 000 000 000 rows. Each rows has got a timestamp column with index created on this column. 
Most frequent queries are the once that aggregate data for the specific month - for example January 2016. If we assign a separete identificator for every month, lets call it "idm" and for January 2016 make it equal 1 (February 2016 = 2 and so on), create index on idm, would it have any effect on query performance comparing WHERE statements :

1. timestamp >= '20160101' AND timestamp < '20160201'
2. idm = 1
   ?
   Would using idm be faster?

Comment: Obviously it would be faster as search argument is straight forward and you will be having index on idm

Comment: @MihirShah sadly these things are not obvious. Adding data to the row size is likely to make things slower due to increased disk reads. The query is likely doing an index scan anyway so is only going to be seeking the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an index on `timestamp` and on the proposed `idm` column, then the two would probably be identical.  This an an approximate answer.  If you have other  conditions in the `where` clause, then the `idm = 1` is better for performance.  It allows more ways of using optimization.

However, indexes are not the right approach.  Because of the nature of your data and queries, you should consider table partitions.  This would allow each month of data to be stored separately.  You can read about table partitioning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx).

If you don't want to partition the tables, I would recommend making `idm` or `timestamp` a clustered index.  This will help queries, even the where clause selects a relatively high proportion of rows in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Table partitioning seems complicated and I am not sure if it will work in our environment, but maybe  I will give it a try. :)